# "Please specify a shipping method"

Tags: magento2, shipping

What I'm doing is

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($shipping->getData());
```

where

```
$shipping = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();`
```

However, I'm getting `Please specify a shipping method.` on quote save. I've also tried to do

```
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);

    $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
```

But it's not helping. Any idea what I'm missing? It's a custom module I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Make sure your shipping method is active from backend or else check any extension is not hiding it via plugin or observer.

Answer (score 0):

Its a common message for both shipping method and collectTotals, so if your shipping method is right then check for later's implementation. All shipping methods have their own module, so get your shipping method from quote and look for its collecTotals definition. In my case shipping method was only set for a particular store.